# Checking to see if an Oracle listener is running without installing the client?

Tags: oracle, sockets

Is it possible to check if an Oracle listener is running on a remote machine without using the Oracle client?

Perhaps by connecting to specific port on a remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to check.

You could try to telnet to port 1521 (or whatever port you expect the listener to be listening on).  If the connection is successful, that would imply that there is a listener.  You're not going to be able to see, however, what services are registered with the listener.  And you won't be able to see whether the listener would actually be able to hand off a connection to the database.  That's why it generally doesn't make a lot of sense to monitor the listener in isolation-- you generally want to monitor whether you can successfully connect to the database not whether the listener process is running.

Comment: Sounds logical.  Thanks.